# Remove colons from time column in pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime

I am trying to convert my SampleTime column from '%H:%M:%S' [seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3N7AK.png) to just '%H%M%S', so removing the colons. I am trying this code:

```
 insitu_time =  pd.to_datetime(insitu['SampleTime']).dt.strftime('%H%M%S')
```

but getting error 'TypeError: <type 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime'

Comment: Can you post sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the data is clean. Here is an example when data intentionally created with white spaces.

```
insitu = pd.DataFrame({'Sampletime': [' 00:30:00', '01:00:01', '01:30:00', '02:00:01 ']})
```

Try to run this to see if it returns any NaT

```
pd.to_datetime(insitu['Sampletime'],errors='coerce')

#0                   NaT
#1   2020-08-07 01:00:01
#2   2020-08-07 01:30:00
#3   2020-08-07 02:00:01
```

Strip the white spaces:

```
insitu['Sampletime'] = insitu['Sampletime'].str.strip()
```

Also try to convert to Timestamp first:

```
insitu['Sampletime'] = insitu['Sampletime'].apply(pd.Timestamp)
```

Then:

```
pd.to_datetime(insitu['Sampletime']).dt.strftime('%H%M%S')

# Result:
#0    003000
#1    010001
#2    013000
#3    020001
```